# How to prevent a drop down box from resizing

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I'm using C# and jquery.  I have a dropdown box that has 20 elements in it.  It is sized according to the text of the largest element.

I have a checkbox.  When the user clicks the checkbox, all of the selections are removed from the dropdown box.  The problem is that when this happens, the box gets smaller and looks kind of awkward.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Width` property of the ASP.NET Control, or use CSS to set the `width` client-side. If you want to dynamically determine the width, do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var width = $('#ddlID').width();
    $('#ddlID').css('width', width);
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/89nS4/

Answer (score 0):

atleast have the default set for the check box like "Please Select" and then append the dynamic content on button select and in css just write this select{width: 300px} some fix width

```
yourcombo.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
```

and add the above answer to make it more efficient

Comment: Applying the following CSS class to the select still does not work:    .selectbox
{
    width:400;
    min-width:400;
}

Comment: set a default value at index 0